# How to turn turtle back and remain on the exact same track?

Tags: netlogo

I want to turn turtle back to the start point but remain on the same track back, I followed these codes:

```
turtles-own [path]

to setup
ca
crt 1
[ set color red
  set path (list patch-here)
  pd 
  repeat 100
   [ rt (random 91 - 45)
     fd 1
     set path fput patch-here path
   ]
 ]
end

to go
ask turtles
[set color blue 
  foreach path 
   [a-patch -> set heading towards a-patch
   fd 1]
 ]
end
```

It did make turtle turn back to the start, but not on the exact same path. So how can I remain turtle on the same path to turn it back to the start point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ask a turtle to face a patch, it will always face the center of the patch, which is what your turtle does while backtracking.

In the initial walk though, your turtle is not restricted to only facingthe centers. So either you will have to make it so that your turtle faces the center of a patch on both the way out and the way back, or you have to record the exact coordinates the turtle was on rather than the patch.

First example: This one uses `move-to` instead of working with `heading`, and just always goes to the center of the patch

```
turtles-own [path]

to setup-1
ca
crt 1
[ set color red
  set path (list patch-here)
  pd 
  repeat 100
   [ rt (random 91 - 45)
     move-to patch-ahead 1
     set path fput patch-here path
   ]
 ]
end

to go-1
ask turtles
[set color blue 
  foreach path 
   [a-patch -> move-to a-patch
   ]
 ]
end
```

Second example: Here I work with the coordinates instead of the patches. That means that at each step, you record of `list` of `xcor` and `ycor` which you then store in the bigger list. Upon turning back, you can then backtrack using these exact coordinates. I used `facexy` and `fd 1` to keep with your way of doing it, but personally I would probably just use `setxy` instead.
Also noticed how I use `butfirst path` in `go-2`, otherwise it tries facing the patch on which it is already standing for the first step which gives you a path that deviates slightly.

```
to setup-2
  ca
  crt 1
  [ set color red
    set path (list (list xcor ycor))
    pd 
    repeat 100
    [ rt (random 91 - 45)
      fd 1
      set path fput (list xcor ycor) path
    ]
  ]
end

to go-2
  ask turtles
  [set color blue 
    foreach butfirst path 
    [a-coord -> facexy item 0 a-coord item 1 a-coord 
    fd 1]
  ]
end
```

Third example: For this last example, I don't record patches or coordinates but instead record the `heading`. On the backtrack, you then just invert the heading by subtracting 180. One interesting effect is that it no longer matters where exactly the turtle is. It will move according to the exact opposite pattern that it initially moved, but you could for example make the steps bigger or smaller, or slightly shift the entire path to the left

```
to setup-3
  ca
  crt 1
  [ set color red
    set path (list heading)
    pd 
    repeat 100
    [ rt (random 91 - 45)
      fd 1
      set path fput heading path
    ]
  ]
end

to go-3
  ask turtles
  [set color blue 
    foreach path 
    [a-heading -> set heading a-heading - 180 
    fd 1]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, open needs to check on the wrapping world, the first approach is the best one to remain on the exact same track backward.

Comment: This loop: foreach path [a-patch -> move-to a-patch ] how can it make the turtle turn around? My understanding is the patch is a list, it saves the turtle trace as patch coordinates in a list, the order for this list starts with the first move to the stop. This loop just called each item in the list, but it did not reverse the order of the list, which should be the last one at the first. How come it did not change the order of the items in the list but made the turtle to turn around on the same track back to the start?

Comment: @user22567873 I'm a bit surprised by this question seeing as you use the same structure in your initial question. The reason it works is because you make your path list in reverse order, adding each new patch to the start of the last rather than adding it to the end.

Comment: what do you mean? This is the question about the initial one. So, you mean that the list was added each pcor in a reversed order? Which means the last patch pcor listed at the left-hand side of the list? Is this a default setting? I checked the list is not like that, it starts from the first patch and end up with the last, so why the codes did not change the order of the list  but can make turtle turn around  backward the start? Thanks.

Comment: @user22567873 your own code uses `set path fput patch-here path`. Do you mean you copied that code from somewhere else but dont really understand it? In that case, normally you would use `lput` to add a value to a list if you want them chronologically, since that adds it to the end. But because this list would have to be flipped around anyway the original author of that code decided to just make the list in reverse order right from the start, hence why they use `fput` instead of `lput`

Comment: that is much clear, thanks a lot about this